# Pandas update doesn't do anything

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some information on it. I created another dataframe that is larger and has default values in it. I want to update the default dataframe with the values from the first dataframe. I'm using df.update but nothing is happening. Here is the code:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(25))
new_df['Column1'] = 1
new_df['Column2'] = 2
new_df.update(old_df)
```

Here, old_df has 2 rows, indexed 5,6 with some random values in Column1 and Column2 and nothing else. I'm expecting these rows to overwrite the default values in new_df, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the old_df? if you are expecting to return anything it won't since update is an inplace operation and it returns None. did you check the new_df after the update?

Comment: Make sure the columns names are the same

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, so I assume the problem is in the part of the code you haven't shown us.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(25))

old_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[5,6])

new_df['Column1'] = 1
new_df['Column2'] = 2

old_df['Column1'] = np.nan
old_df['Column2'] = np.nan
old_df.loc[5,'Column1'] = 9
old_df.loc[6,'Column2'] = 7
new_df.update(old_df)

print(new_df.head(10))
```

Output:

```
   Column1  Column2
0      1.0      2.0
1      1.0      2.0
2      1.0      2.0
3      1.0      2.0
4      1.0      2.0
5      9.0      2.0
6      1.0      7.0
7      1.0      2.0
8      1.0      2.0
9      1.0      2.0
```

Comment: The code is the same as far as the logic goes. The difference is the contents of the dataframes. I don't see how that could make a difference however as when I check the column names for the two dataframes it returns True for all column names. Other than that the overlapping df shares some indices with the other df so the values should simply overwrite the other values.

Comment: Well, does the code I posted works for you? Can you re-create a simple example, similar to mine but with your data, that doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide us how you construct/get *old_df*, before do the update, make sure that the type of both indexes is the same.

```py
new_df.index = new_df.index.astype('int64')
old_df.index = old_df.index.astype('int64')
```

One *int* is not equal to one *string* `1 != '1'`. So update() doesn't found common rows in yours dataframes and as nothing to do.